# Build a debian package that pulls code from GIT on dpkg

Tags: debian

I have a shell script that performs specific tasks on execution. Its purpose is to either install a set of git repositories on a server or update the code base that has already been installed on the server.

These tasks are:

- Creates directories to deploy each repository in if absent
- Clone code from GIT for a fresh installation or pull the latest code from git
- Ask the user for configuration details regarding the database. Imports a sql file on a fresh installation
- Updates files and links
- Install dependencies using apt-get

How can I build this into a debian package so that these tasks are performed on dpkg?

I have been unable to figure out where to perform these tasks from the Debian documentation.

Comment: You can use Gentoo :)

Comment: This seems like a poor fit for a Debian package. Is there a reason you're not packaging the individual Git projects as individual packages?

Comment: @tripleee could you elaborate on how I would do that?

Comment: How is that unclear? In each Git project, create a `debian/rules` and the other stuff you need to make a Debian package. Maybe create some build automation to build and publish a new version of that package when you update the `master` branch in Git. Now your top-level package can simply depend on your other packages, and a reguar `apt-get upgrade` will fetch the newest version of everything.